# How to use polymorphism to execute command on objects, which have no common base class?

Tags: c++, architecture

I am receiveing commands through json, which I insert in to a pipe. For this reason thye must have the same base class.
The pipe is read by a pipe handler, some commands are consumed by the pipe handler, others have to be passed down to a device, which is a member of the pipe handler. I could simply do this:

```
class Command{};
class HandlerCommand : public Command {
   void execute(Handler* h);
};
class DeviceCommand : public Command {
   void execute(Device* d);
};

Command* c = pipe.receive();
if (const auto hc  = dynamic_cast<const HandlerCommand*>(c)) { hc.execute( **handlerptr** ); }
else if (const auto dc  = dynamic_cast<const DeviceCommand*>(c))  { dc.execute( **deviceptr** );}
```

Device and pipehandler should not have the same base, since they have no common methods, fields, they are conceptually different.
Is there a way to avoid using dynamic cast here. I was thinking maybe there is some neat design pattern for this, but couldn`t quit come up with a better solution.

EDIT: did not derive DeviceCommand and HandlerCommand from command, fixed this.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` will not work here.  The objects must be derived from `Command` and have at least one virtual function to use it.  Sounds like what you need is a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: use variant and visit

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use polymorphism of two things which have nothing in common. You will need the same base class/interface: in your case `Command`. As mentioned above your base class requires a pure virtual function that must be implemented by the derived classes. I will utilize a `Command * clone()const` prototype, which could be very useful later on. Please introduce a virtual destructor of your base class, otherwise, to track down this memory error could be a pain in the ass. Note, regarding your `dynamic_cast` the member function `execute`, must be `const`. You may try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Handler
{
public:
    Handler(){}
};

class Device
{
public:
    Device(){}
};

enum class CommandType{Handler,Devise};

class Command 
{
public:
    virtual ~Command(){}
    virtual Command*clone()const = 0;
    virtual CommandType getType()const = 0;
};
class HandlerCommand : public Command {
public:
    HandlerCommand():Command(){}
    void execute(Handler* h) const
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__<<"\n";
    }

    HandlerCommand*clone()const { return new HandlerCommand(*this); }
    CommandType getType()const { return CommandType::Handler; }
};
class DeviceCommand : public Command{
public:
    DeviceCommand():Command(){}
    void execute(Device* d)const
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__<<"\n";
    }
    DeviceCommand*clone()const { return new DeviceCommand(*this); }
    CommandType getType()const { return CommandType::Devise; }
};


int main()
{
    Device dev;
    Handler handler;
    std::vector<Command*> pipe{ new HandlerCommand(), new DeviceCommand() };

    while (!pipe.empty())
    {
        Command* c = pipe.back(); 
        if (c->getType() ==  CommandType::Handler) { static_cast<const HandlerCommand*>(c)->execute(&handler); }
        else if (c->getType() == CommandType::Devise ) { static_cast<const DeviceCommand*>(c)->execute(&dev); }

        delete c;

        pipe.pop_back();

    }

    std::cin.get();


}
```

outputs:

```
DeviceCommand::execute
HandlerCommand::execute
```

Version 2.0 using `std::variant`. You will need at least C++17 to compile this. Note, a single `pipe` container can exclusively comprise one of the mentioned classes within the variant. So there is no casting anymore, but you will need two pipes. Because of that, I introduced a time stamp variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

class Handler
{
public:
    Handler() {}
};

class Device
{
public:
    Device() {}
};




class HandlerCommand  {
    int ts;
public:
    HandlerCommand(int _ts):ts(_ts) {}
    void execute(Handler* h) const
    {
        std::cout << ts << ": "<< __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
    int timeStamp()const { return ts; }
};
class DeviceCommand  {
    int ts;
public:
    DeviceCommand(int _ts) :ts(_ts) {}
    void execute(Device* d)const
    {
        std::cout << ts << ": " << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
    int timeStamp()const { return ts; }
};


using Command = std::variant<HandlerCommand, DeviceCommand>;

int main()
{
    Device dev;
    Handler handler;
    std::vector<Command> hcPipe{HandlerCommand(2),HandlerCommand(5)};
    std::vector<Command> dcPipe{DeviceCommand(1),DeviceCommand(4)};

    Command single = DeviceCommand(0);

    if (single.index() == 0)
    {
        std::get<HandlerCommand>(single).execute(&handler);
    }
    else
    {
        std::get<DeviceCommand>(single).execute(&dev);
    }


    while (!hcPipe.empty() || !dcPipe.empty())
    {
        if (!hcPipe.empty() && (dcPipe.empty() || std::get<HandlerCommand>(hcPipe.front()).timeStamp() < std::get<DeviceCommand>(dcPipe.front()).timeStamp()))
        {
            std::get<HandlerCommand>(hcPipe.front()).execute(&handler);
            hcPipe.erase(hcPipe.begin());
        }
        else
        {
            std::get<DeviceCommand>(dcPipe.front()).execute(&dev);
            dcPipe.erase(dcPipe.begin());
        }

    }


    std::cin.get();
}
```

outputs:

```
0: DeviceCommand::execute
1: DeviceCommand::execute
2: HandlerCommand::execute
4: DeviceCommand::execute
5: HandlerCommand::execute
```

Comment: yeah, this is the original problem I meant, just left out the base class from Command, my question is if there is a way here to get rid of the dynamic cast

Comment: a added a second version without dynamic_cast but with common base class. Hope that helps